# Flex IViewport implementation

Tags: flash, apache-flex, containers

Does anyone know of a link/book that might have example implementation of the IViewport interface in Flex. I'm trying to figure out how a component/container that implements this needs to behave when the scroll positions changes etc. The reference documentation doesn't make this very clear.

If anyone has more in-depth info on this it would be greatly helpful.

thanks

Comment: I would checkout the `GroupBase` class which is where this interface is implemented. There's probably a ton of unrelated code in `GroupBase` but you only need to focus on the handful of properties and the two methods that `IViewport` defines. Finally, from looking at the interface, it looks like `IViewport` is doesn't do anything when the scroll position changes (just a hunch) ... it only is responsible for telling the thing that contains the viewport how many pixels it should scroll the content that is contained inside the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, take a look at the GroupBase implementation of it. Essentially IViewport methods on GroupBase delegate to the corresponding methods on the GroupBase's layout (an instance of LayoutBase, which is also worth a read). Setting GroupBase's `verticalScrollPosition` and `horizontalScrollPosition` (which is what the Spark ScrollBars do when you move them) ultimately result in LayoutBase updating the `scrollRect` property on your component's `DisplayObject` superclass to those values which correspond to pixel offsets from the left and top of the component.

For info on the `scrollRect` property check out these links:

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scrollRect
- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e17.html

As LayoutBase and all its subclasses are all built to work with GroupBase you may want to just extend GroupBase for your component. If you don't want to use a LayoutBase subclass at all then this should surmise what you need to implement to have your component work with a Spark ScrollBar:

#### `contentWidth` / `contentHeight`

These are your scrollable component's full width and height in pixels if it wasn't being clipped / scrolled - this is where a ScrollBar reads its maximum value from and should be set after your component has measured/calculated its full height.

#### `verticalScrollPosition` / `horizontalScrollPosition`

This is the number of pixels out of the full contentWidth / Height that you have scrolled. It is set by the appropriate vertical / horizontal scrollbar and your implementation should result in your component setting its own `scrollRect` to a value like

`scrollRect = new Rectangle(
    horizontalScrollPosition, verticalScrollPosition, width, height);`

#### `getHorizontalScrollPositionDelta` / `getVerticalScrollPositionDelta`

These will return the amount to move for a particular navigation action such as page up / page down. For instance, you want the view to scroll three rows when the user hits the down arrow on their keyboard. When the user does this, the scrollbar will call

`yourComponent.getVerticalScrollPositionDelta(NavigationUnit.DOWN)`

Your implementation should work out the height of three rows and return it. The scrollbar will then update your `verticalScrollPosition` value with the updated value which in turn causes the `scrollRect` to update as described for that property above. The set of different units you will need to account for can be found here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/core/NavigationUnit.html

#### `clipAndEnableScrolling`

You don't need to worry about this unless you want the component to be able to enable or disable its ability to scroll at runtime in which case check out `LayoutBase.updateScrollRect()`